# Add a constant value to a numerical attribute in Rapid Miner

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, rapidminer

I am working with rapidminer , I have a dataset with a numerical field (attribute) , I want to simply add a constant (e.g. 1) to all values of this feature ,

How may I do this? I have not found anything straightforward so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Data Transformation > Attribute Set Reduction... > Generation > Generate Attributes

Use a function to create a new column, adding 1 to the value of the old column

If your original attribute is "X1",then the expression should be something like "X1 + 1"

Video here:

http://vancouverdata.blogspot.ca/2011/08/rapidminer-etl-transforming-attributes.html